# Image and Video Lightbox in page tab iframe

Tags: facebook, tabs, lightbox

I got a page tab - ok - so far so good. 
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Team-Vermont/210976122316498?sk=app_201737266589689
I want the user to click on video 1 and have a youtube vid play in a lightbox. Right now all I can figure out is the ugly onclick popper.

So - images and video in a popup on an iframe page tab. What is the secret?

I seriously have been searching for answers for about 6 hours and tried and failed about 12 times.

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried shadowbox - no dice - I got it working as an onclick popup - but its ugly . I have been reading a lot about display=popup and FB.ui() -but I am not sure how that will work unless I create an album for the user with the associated videos and photos (even though ideally it would be html pages) it looks like the  FB.ui()  only pull content from FB - is that right>

Comment: post code of the ugly one, maybe we all can make it pretty.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `<map>` tag, I'm not sure how this would help you to achieve a lightbox effect?

Just a small note, you **cannot** have your lightbox *outside* the page tab iframe overlaying the Facebook content (left sidebar and right *ads* and other components). So in short, you **cannot** have a similar effect to the Facebook photo album!

Just make sure that the lightbox content + padding + borders + shaddow is <= 520 px, otherwise you'll get the ugly horizontal scrollbar!